# Resizebox on Table without textfont exceeding 12pt

Tags: graphics

I'm writing a two-column paper in latex and I'm using \resizebox to adjust table size to paper column width as shown code portion below. However, if table content is not much I face the problem that the table text size is slightly larger than paragraph text size. Is there a way to set a limit on maximum text size scaling or to modify table fontsize + while still using \resizebox?

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\small  
\caption{Results}
\label{tb1}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
        \cline{1-6}
        Sensor& P1 &P2&P3&P4&P5\\ \cline{1-6}       
        Val1 &2  &2  &2 &2 &5  \\ \cline{1-6}           
        Val2 &13 &13 &15 &8 &50 \\ \cline{1-6}          
\end{tabular}}\end{table}
```

Thank you and regards,

Ayomi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resizing tables is not the best way to cope with the problem, better is using `tabular*`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Results}\label{tb1}
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}\hspace{\tabcolsep}}
  cccccc
  @{\hspace{\tabcolsep}}
}
\hline
Sensor& P1 &P2&P3&P4&P5\\
\hline
Val1 &2  &2  &2 &2 &5  \\
\hline
Val2 &13 &13 &15 &8 &50 \\
\hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2-12]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `caption` and `booktabs` you get a better result:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{caption,booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Results}\label{tb1}
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}\hspace{\tabcolsep}}
  cccccc
  @{\hspace{\tabcolsep}}
}
\toprule
Sensor& P1 &P2&P3&P4&P5\\
\midrule
Val1 &2  &2  &2 &2 &5  \\
Val2 &13 &13 &15 &8 &50 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2-12]

\end{document}
```

[image]